# QTreeView: Show "loading" message when expanding item

Tags: pyqt, loading, pyqt4, qtreeview

With PyQT and a QTreeView, I need to display a "loading" message or a "spinning wheel" when the user expands an item, because the childs are retrieved by making a http request.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the time taken to retrieve the child items is relatively short (say, a few seconds), then by far the simplest solution is to display a [busy/wait cursor](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#CursorShape-enum).

You can either set the cursor on the treeview:

```
treeview.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.BusyCursor)
# retrieve and insert child items ...
treeview.unsetCursor()
```

or set it globally:

```
QtGui.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor))
# retrieve and insert child items ...
QtGui.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
```

But other solutions will be much more complicated than this.

For instance you could show a [QProgressBar](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qprogressbar.html) in the status bar, or perhaps use a [QMovie](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmovie.html) to display an animated icon somehow.

Comment: Great and simple solution. Worked on Windows just fine.